how to send content from celery task to websucket
please i am trying to process some data in a celery task and pass it to websucket connection to the clientside  but the bellow code deosnt seam to be doing what i intend to achieve .
Consumers.py file
class DocumentConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect(self):
    self.document_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['document_id']
    self.document_group_name = f'document_{self.document_id}'

    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.document_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()
    logger.info(f"WebSocket connection established for document ID: {self.document_id}")

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.document_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
    logger.info(f"WebSocket connection closed for document ID: {self.document_id}")

async def receive(self, text_data):
    data = json.loads(text_data)
    logger.info(f'Received message: {data}')
    message_type = data.get('type')

    if message_type == 'content_update':
        content = data.get('content')
        if content.strip():
            sentence_errors, sentence_corrections = process_text(content)

            # Send message to room group
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.document_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'document_message',
                    'sentence_errors': sentence_errors,
                    'sentence_corrections': sentence_corrections,
                }
            )

async def document_message(self, event):
    sentence_errors = event['sentence_errors']
    sentence_corrections = event['sentence_corrections']

    # Print the errors and corrections to the terminal
    print(f'Sentence Errors: {sentence_errors}')
    print(f'Sentence Corrections: {sentence_corrections}')

    # Log the received errors and corrections
    logger.info(f'Sentence Errors: {sentence_errors}')
    logger.info(f'Sentence Corrections: {sentence_corrections}')

    # Send errors and corrections back to the client
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'sentence_errors': sentence_errors,
        'sentence_corrections': sentence_corrections,
    }))

task.py
@shared_task
def process_document_task(document_id):
print(f'hello {document_id}')
logger.info(f"Started processing document with ID: {document_id}")

try:
    document = Document.objects.get(id=document_id)
    file_path = document.file.path
    
    logger.info(f"Extracting text from document: {file_path}")
    doc_content = extract_text_from_docx(file_path)
    logger.info(f"text: {doc_content}")
    
    if doc_content.strip():
        chunks = [doc_content[i:i + 1000] for i in range(0, len(doc_content), 1000)]
        sentence_errors = []
        sentence_corrections = {}

        logger.info(f"Processing text chunks")
        for chunk in chunks:
            chunk_errors, chunk_corrections = process_text(chunk)
            sentence_errors.extend(chunk_errors)
            sentence_corrections.update(chunk_corrections)
        logger.info(f"text: {sentence_corrections}")
        logger.info(f"Text processing complete for document: {document_id}")
    
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        f'document_{document.id}',
        {
            'type': 'document_message',
            'sentence_errors': sentence_errors,
            'sentence_corrections': sentence_corrections
        }
    )
    logger.info(f"Sent processed data for document: {document_id} to channel layer")

except Document.DoesNotExist:
    logger.error(f"Document with ID {document_id} does not exist.")
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error processing document with ID {document_id}: {e}")

logger.info(f"Finished processing document with ID: {document_id}")

to verify if the content is being recieved in the cosumers.py file i tried printing it to the terminal but its not being printed .
and in my task.py file the
logger.info(f"Sent processed data for document: {document_id} to channel layer")

is being logged to my celery logs
